# Show that $P\left(\left\{\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}X_n\geq X\right\}\right)=1$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, limsup-and-liminf, borel-cantelli-lemmas

> Let be $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ a probability space and $X_1,X_2,\dots$ a sequence of random variables. Show that if for a random variable $X$ and for all $\epsilon>0$ the infinite sum $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}P\left(\left\{X-X_n>\epsilon\right\}\right)$ converges, then $P\left(\left\{\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}X_n\geq X\right\}\right)=1$.
>
> (Hint: *Borel-Cantelli-Lemma*)

---

**My approach:**

We immediately see that $M:=\left\{\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}X_n\geq X\right\}$ can be expressed by
$$
M=\bigcap\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}\bigcap\limits_{i=j}^{\infty}\left\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)-X_{n_i}(\omega)<\frac{1}{m}\right\}.
$$
We know that for an $\omega\in\Omega$ there exists a subsequence $(X_{n_j}(\omega))_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $\lim\limits_{j\to\infty}X_{n_j}(\omega)=\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}X_{n}(\omega)$ and by means of probability and set operations we get:
\begin{align*}
&1\geq P(M)=1-P(M^c)=1-P\left(\left(\bigcap\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}\bigcap\limits_{i=j}^{\infty}\left\{X-X_{n_i}<\frac{1}{m}\right\}\right)^c\right)\\
&=1-P\left(\bigcup\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcap\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{i=j}^{\infty}\left\{X-X_{n_i}\geq\frac{1}{m}\right\}\right)=1-P\left(\bigcup\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(\limsup_{j\to\infty}\left\{X-X_{n_j}\geq\frac{1}{m}\right\}\right)\right)\\
&\geq 1-\sum\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}P\left(\limsup_{j\to\infty}\left\{X-X_{n_j}\geq\frac{1}{m}\right\}\right)=1-\sum\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}0=1,
\end{align*}
because of Borel-Cantelli-Lemma
$$
\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}P\left(\left\{X-X_{n_j}>\epsilon\right\}\right)<\infty\implies P\left(\limsup\limits_{j\to\infty}\left\{X-X_{n_j}>\epsilon\right\} \right)=0.
$$
So we get $P(M)=1$ which proves the statement.

---

I had a little discussion with my tutor because she told me that my proof is wrong and I can't do it this way. However, she was unable to explain to me where my approach breaks?!

Maybe someone can give me a hint where I am wrong or can confirm that it is correct.

---

**EDIT:**

I think I got the mistake. The above expression of $M$ is wrong beause we have to take care of the two cases $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}X_n= X$ and $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}X_n> X$. So it must be
\begin{align*}
&M=\bigcap\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}\bigcap\limits_{i=j}^{\infty}\left\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)-X_{n_i}(\omega)<\frac{1}{m}\right\}\\
&\cup \bigcup\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcap\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{i=j}^{\infty}\left\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X_{n_i}(\omega)-X(\omega)>\frac{1}{m}\right\}\\
&\implies \bigcap\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}\bigcap\limits_{i=j}^{\infty}\left\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)-X_{n_i}(\omega)<\frac{1}{m}\right\}\subseteq M\\
&\implies P(M)\geq P\left(\bigcap\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}\bigcap\limits_{i=j}^{\infty}\left\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)-X_{n_i}(\omega)<\frac{1}{m}\right\}\right)\\
&=1-P\left(\left(\bigcap\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}\bigcap\limits_{i=j}^{\infty}\left\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)-X_{n_i}(\omega)<\frac{1}{m}\right\}\right)^c\right)=\underset{\text{Borel-Cantelli-Lemma}}{\dots\dots} = 1.
\end{align*}

Comment: Every time you write something like $X_{n_i}$ it seems you actually mean $X_i$.

Comment: @EricWofsey, no, I am referring to the subsequence which converges to $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}X_n$

Comment: Then $n_i$ is a function of $\omega$ and you should make it clear in your notation, and be explicit about exactly how you are defining it.

Comment: In any case, it is not clear to me why you want to use such a subsequence.  It looks to me like your proof is basically correct if you replace $X_{n_i}$ with $X_i$ everywhere.

Comment: @EricWofsey, maybe this is the point where I was wrong. My idea was as follows, we take an arbitrary $\omega\in\Omega$ and plug it into the sequence of random variables, so we get a real valued sequence i.e. $(X_n(\omega))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. Then, $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}X_n(\omega)$ exists and we find a subsequence such that $\lim\limits_{j\to\infty}X_{n_j}(\omega)=\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}X_n(\omega)$.

Comment: Do you mean for "an" epsilon or for all epsilon?

Comment: The claim seems false. Let $X_n=-1,\forall n,X=0$. Then $P(-1>\varepsilon)=0,\,\forall n$ so $\sum_nP(X_n>\varepsilon)=0$ but $\liminf_nX_n=-1$ and $P(\liminf_nX_n\geq 0)=0$.

Comment: @Philipp . The gramatically correct sentence in that case would be for "any" arbitrary epsilon and not "an" .

Comment: Let us fix an $\epsilon>0$ .Well intuitively what you are claiming is that there is a set of measure $1$ (the complement of the limsup) such that for each $\omega$ in it , $X_{n}(\omega)$ exceeds $X(\omega)$ by  $\epsilon$ only finitely times(by very definition of limsup) . But on the other hand $\lim\inf X_{n}\geq X$.

Comment: @Snoop, so this means my proof must be wrong. But I don't see where I missed something!?

Comment: @Philipp maybe it's because you have written $X-X_n$ instead of $X_n-X$ as in the claim

Comment: @Snoop, there is a typo in the claim which adresses your hint. I have fixed it. This invalidates your counter example.